# How to become vertical align by using bootstrap responsive flex column?

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, responsive, vertical-alignment

How to make text title "Latest news" to go below the "new" icon after screen size smaller than 576px? I have tried to use bootstrap flex column to do responsive but failed many times. please help!!

[page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJRqa.png)

Here is my code

```
<div class="latest-news">
    <div class="title d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img class="icon01 px-2" src="img/title-icon01.png">
        <span class="title01 px-2">Latest news</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do what you request by using flex-column and flex-sm-row.

`flex-column` will put the text under the icon (for all screen-sizes)
`flex-sm-row` will put the text next to the icon (for all screen-sizes **larger** than the sm breakpoint (576px)).

```
<div class="latest-news">
    <div class="title d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img class="icon01 px-2" src="img/title-icon01.png">
        <span class="title01 px-2">Latest news</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to learn more about responsive design with bootstrap, their documentation is an excellent place to start. This link shows the explanation with flex-column:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#direction

Comment: Thanks! it worked out well. okay, i will check out their site and practice more: )